# Plotly - Table not displaying properly until column moved / rerendered

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am using Plotly to display data in a simple table.  I've populated in some dummy data below.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
data = [go.Table(
    columnorder = [1,2],    
    header = dict(
        values = ['<b>'+'TENOR'+'</b>'] + list(['a','b','c','d','e']),
        line_color = 'darkslategray',
        fill_color = 'royalblue',
        align = 'center',
        font = dict(color = 'white', size = 12),
        height = 20
        ),
    cells = dict(
        values = [['row1','row2','row3'],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]],
        line_color = 'darkslategray',
        fill = dict(color=['paleturquoise', 'white']),
        align = ['right', 'center'],
        font_size = 12,
        height = 20)
    )]

fig = go.Figure(data = data)
fig.show()
```

When I run this (Jupyter, but same result happens in a couple other IDEs too) it initially displays as:

[image]

Then, as soon as I move a column / manipulate it in any way, it then redisplays (**properly**, except the column that I've moved) as:

[image]

Any idea why it's not rendering correctly in the first place?  I basically took this right from one of [their table examples](https://plotly.com/python/table/#tables-in-dash)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment out your line `columnorder = [1,2,3,4,5],`.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
data = [go.Table(
    #columnorder = [1,2],    
    header = dict(
        values = ['<b>'+'TENOR'+'</b>'] + list(['a','b','c','d','e']),
        line_color = 'darkslategray',
        fill_color = 'royalblue',
        align = 'center',
        font = dict(color = 'white', size = 12),
        height = 20
        ),
    cells = dict(
        values = [['row1','row2','row3'],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]],
        line_color = 'darkslategray',
        fill = dict(color=['paleturquoise', 'white']),
        align = ['right', 'center'],
        font_size = 12,
        height = 20)
    )]

fig = go.Figure(data = data)
fig.show()
```

Specifying that is saying you only want to show those listed columns.

**Alternatively**, change that line to `columnorder = [0,1,2,3,4,5],`.